# How to remove a file inside a folder from current selection in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, selection

Say I have several folders and bunch of files inside each of them. I want to copy it all expect for one file inside one of the folders. I don't want to temporally move the file and then put it back. Is there a way to keep all the folders selected and remove one file from the selection? Or do I just have to manually move everything back and forth?

Comment: There is probably a power shell command that can do it, maybe someone will post it.

Comment: 1) Do you want to preserve the folder structure?


2) Does the file you want to exclude's name contain a pattern like 'Everything containging z0r.dontinclude.txt'?


3) Is the reason that you do not want to copy that one file because some process is writing to it?

Answer (score 1):

From the GUI:

`Ctrl + A` will select all items in a folder.

Using `Ctrl + Left click` on currently selected items will deselect ONLY that item.

Using `Shift + Left click` will 'collapse' the selection from the top of the folder list to the item you left clicked on. Everything beneath that item will no longer be selected.

There's a bunch of hotkeys similar to this available in Windows which are always nice and help. You can find the list here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-7